# FLUTTER - TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have been initializing Firebase like this since I started by following this [**flutter documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web), but for some reason, this throws an error in the debugger, as follows:

> TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be
> invoked without 'new'

Could you please help me rectify this?

Here is the Flutter code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pace/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:pace/pages/auth_page.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AuthPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the Dart SDK version constraint in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: sdk: '>=3.3.0-147.0.dev <4.0.0'

Comment: That sounds like a Flutter SDK version.  The current stable version of Dart is 3.2.4.

Comment: How can we fix this?

Comment: Once again: what is the Dart version specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file?  Better yet, edit your question and post the entire filee.

Comment: This sounds like a JavaScript error.  Is this happening with a Flutter web app?

Comment: It was a dependency error, created the same project from another machine and it works properly.
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

Comment: Could you be more explicit on how this was fixed? I started a new Flutter project and received the same debug-pausing error; changing the pubspec.yaml to a lower (3.1.5) flutter sdk doesn't seem to be sufficient - were there any changes to the web/index.html or other files?

Comment: I couldn't find fix.
I was running the code on macOS Sonoma, any web app with Firebase connection fails in that machine, but when I started coding on a machine with macOS Monterey, it works without any issues.

I am not sure how does this resolve my issues, but it does.

When I run "flutter create project" in macOS Monterey terminal  it gives

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

if i run the same command in macOS Sonoma, it gives

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0-273.0.dev <4.0.0'

So the issue must be this sdk, but just changing it in Pubspec.yaml doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and cannot do web releases therefore currently :/

Comment: Found a solution: Deleted the Flutter SDK and reinstalled using VS Code, now the error is gone. @FelixMittermeier, maybe it would help you too.

Answer (score 22):

As Tahsin Emre suggested in a comment; if this error occurs when updating to Flutter 3.19.0, it can be solved by upgrading the various Firebase package versions. The problem was solved for me with the following versions in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
 dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^2.25.4
  cloud_functions: ^4.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.5
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.5
```

Comment: Worked for me too.
Strangely flutter pub outdated didn't show the outdated firebase packages, i wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

I occurred into the same error while trying to release my app on web and after a few attempts I have eventually found a solution for it.
Here are the steps I have performed:

1. Run `flutter channel stable` to make sure that you are currently using a `stable` channel and not a `beta`
2. Run `flutter upgrade` to update to the latest version of the SDK, Dart SDK will update accordingly.
3. Run `flutter --version` to check both your Flutter SDK version and your Dart SDK version.
4. Make sure that your `pubspec.yaml` includes you Dart SDK version in the version constraints specified. (Example: if your Dart SDK version shown in the output provided from `flutter --version` is 2.19.4, make sure that your code looks something like this `sdk: '>=2.19.0 <4.0.0'` at least).
5. In my case scenario, the issue is solved using Flutter SDK version 3.7.0 with Dart SDK version 2.19.0, however this is not the latest version, but I am confident that even with the last stable version ( Flutter SDK 3.16.5) the issue shouldn't occur.

Hopefully this solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade from **beta** to **stable**.

Comment: But just using an older version does not actually solve the issue, it's only a workaround for now but not future-proof.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to downgrade to a previous version. You can use the [latest release](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes) which by the time (2024-03-15) I'm writing this answer is `3.19.0`. So to solve the issue, please upgrade the Firebase package to the latest versions inside the `pubspec.yaml` file too:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^2.27.1
  cloud_functions: ^4.6.9
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.9
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.9
```

I got these versions from [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core), [cloud_functions](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions), [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) packages for Flutter. So I recommend always keeping your packages up to date.