# TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: flutter, firebase

## TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Mg8.jpg)

**Could you please help me rectify this?

Here is the Flutter code**

````
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}```
````

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77705647/